# python nested list comprehension and text formating

Tags: python, list, string-formatting, list-comprehension

I am having some difficulty trying to format data extracted from a dictionary, which will be used to compose an email.
I am trying to use list comprehension to a) minimize the amount of code sent to the email function and b) to remove the outer brackets on my dictionary values and insert a newline;

Code:

```
test_dict = {'A': [['ap11', 'ct1', 'status a'],
                   ['ap2', 'ct2', 'status b'],
                   ['ap11', 'ct1', 'status a']],
             'B': [['ap33', 'ct3', 'status b']]}

for k, v in test_dict.iteritems():
    site_id = k
    alert_header = str(['aname', 'cname', 'status'])
    ap_list = [i for i in v]
    # SendMail(site_id, alert_header, ap_list)
    print(site_id)
    print(alert_header)
    print(ap_list)
```

Output:

```
A
['aname', 'cname', 'status']
[['ap11', 'ct1', 'status a'], ['ap2', 'ct2', 'status b'], ['ap11', 'ct1', 'status a']]
B
['aname', 'cname', 'status']
[['ap33', 'ct3', 'status b']]
```

Desired Output is a single string comprising of the key, the *alert_header* and the str representation of each sublist, one per line:

```
A
['name', 'cname', 'status']
['ap11', 'ct1', 'status a']
['ap2', 'ct2', 'status b']
['ap11', 'ct1', 'status a']
B
['name', 'cname', 'status']
['ap33', 'ct3', 'status b']
```

TIA

Comment: Why format do you actually want? What are you going to be passing exactly, a list, str ..? Also you don't need to continually recreate  alert_header  in the loop, create it once outside

Comment: I need to pass the header, as an email will be sent for each key in the dictionary. The section in "Desired Output" is what will appear in the body of my email. I am attempting to pass the output to an email function ... SendMail(site_id, alert_header, ap_list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a single string to send:

```
test_dict = {'A': [['ap11', 'ct1', 'status a'],
                   ['ap2', 'ct2', 'status b'],
                   ['ap11', 'ct1', 'status a']],
             'B': [['ap33', 'ct3', 'status b']]}

alert_header = str(['aname', 'cname', 'status'])

for site_id, v in test_dict.iteritems():
    # call str on each sublist and separate by newlines.
    data = "\n".join(map(str, v)) 
    # concatenate all three stings into one.
    to_send = site_id + "\n" + alert_header + "\n" + data
    print(to_send)
```

Output:

```
A
['aname', 'cname', 'status']
['ap11', 'ct1', 'status a']
['ap2', 'ct2', 'status b']
['ap11', 'ct1', 'status a']
B
['aname', 'cname', 'status']
[['ap33', 'ct3', 'status b']]
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. Not sure why my question was down voted, did I not ask it correctly?

Comment: @zeepi, no worries, maybe making it more obvious  i.e that you want a single string per k/v pairing would help your question.

Answer (score 0):

using the string representation of a list is not a good idea, but if you really need to do, use a for-loop to print the sublists:

```
for site_id, ap_list in test_dict.iteritems():
    alert_header = ['aname', 'cname', 'status']
    print(site_id)
    print(alert_header)
    for ap in ap_list:
        print(ap)
```

Comment: I was able to get the desired output using a for loop, unfortunately I can't pass a for loop to my email function...SendMail(site_id, alert_header, ap_list)